# Ionic If Else Condition

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have three slides that want to be showed, but for a certain user they can only access one slides as meet the condition.

I give an example, my user package_type is 11.
So she only can view zumba slide only and two others are hidden.

Same goes to other user, they can only view for certain slide that are accessible for them.

I have tried this, but seems doesn't work.

workout.ts

```
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
this.userDetails = data.userData;
this.weightSlide = true;
this.cardioSlide = true;
  this.zumbaSlide = true;

   if (this.userDetails.package_type == '3') {
      this.weightSlide = true;
    console.log(this.userDetails.package_type);}
    else if (this.userDetails.package_type == '8') {
    this.cardioSlide = true;
    console.log(this.userDetails.package_type);}
    else if (this.userDetails.package_type == '11' ) {
      this.zumbaSlide = true;
        ((this.weightSlide = false) || (this.cardioSlide = false));
        console.log(this.userDetails.package_type);}
    else {
      this.weightSlide = false;
      this.cardioSlide = false;
      this.zumbaSlide = false;
      console.log(this.userDetails.package_type);
    }
```

This is workout.html

```
<!--
  Generated template for the SlidePage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->



<ion-content class="tutorial-page">
  <video autoplay loop src="assets/videos/fears.mp4" muted="muted"></video>

    <ion-slides autoplay="4000" pager loop pager muted="muted" *ngIf="weightSlide">
      <ion-slide class="gambar1" style="background-image: url(assets/imgs/workout.jpg);  background-size: 100% 100%;  background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <!--  <img src="assets/imgs/workout.jpg" class="slide-image" /> -->

          <h1 style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;" class="slide-title">Heavy Weight Training</h1>
          <p style="color: #ffffff ">Start your day with training.</p>
            <button ion-button expand="block" (click)="weightPages()">START WORKOUT</button>
          <!-- <p>We use Odd Dollars here </p> -->
          <!-- <p>The first 100 is on us, but then the rest is up to you </p> -->
      </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide *ngIf="cardioSlide">
          <!--  <img src="assets/imgs/workout.jpg" class="slide-image" /> -->

            <h1 style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;" class="slide-title">Cardio Training</h1>
            <p style="color: #ffffff">Be Stronger Than Your Excuses.</p>
              <button ion-button expand="block" (click)="cardioPages()">START CARDIO</button>
            <!-- <p>We use Odd Dollars here </p> -->
            <!-- <p>The first 100 is on us, but then the rest is up to you </p> -->
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide *ngIf="zumbaSlide">
          <!--  <img src="assets/imgs/workout.jpg" class="slide-image" /> -->

            <h1 style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;" class="slide-title">Zumba Training</h1>
            <p style="color: #ffffff">Sweat Is Just Fat.</p>
              <button ion-button expand="block" (click)="zumbaPages()">START ZUMBA</button>
            <!-- <p>We use Odd Dollars here </p> -->
            <!-- <p>The first 100 is on us, but then the rest is up to you </p> -->
        </ion-slide>


    </ion-slides>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: What do you think this does? `((this.weightSlide = true) || (this.cardioSlide = true));`

Comment: sorry it should be false, to justify the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually making them `true` that means every user can access your three slides, to avoid this assign **`false`** to your Slide fields and once you met the condition make them **`true`**.

```
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
this.userDetails = data.userData;
this.weightSlide = false;
this.cardioSlide = false;
this.zumbaSlide = false;

    if (this.userDetails.package_type == '3') {
      this.weightSlide = true;
      console.log(this.userDetails.package_type);
    } else if (this.userDetails.package_type == '8') {
       this.cardioSlide = true;
       console.log(this.userDetails.package_type);
    } else if (this.userDetails.package_type == '11' ) {
        this.zumbaSlide = true;
        console.log(this.userDetails.package_type);
    } else {
      this.weightSlide = false;
      this.cardioSlide = false;
      this.zumbaSlide = false;
      console.log(this.userDetails.package_type);
    }
```

**Edit :**   Is there any specific functionality with this below line if no, then remove it.

```
 ((this.weightSlide = true) || (this.cardioSlide = true))
```

You are disabling complete **`ion-slides`** if  **`weightSlide`**  is set to **`false`**, that's why you are not able to see the correct output. Just change these two lines,

```
 <ion-slides autoplay="4000" pager loop pager muted="muted" >
      <ion-slide class="gambar1" *ngIf="weightSlide" style="background-image: url(assets/imgs/workout.jpg);  background-size: 100% 100%;  background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it change, but show 2 slides instead of 1 slide. Which is weightSlide and zumbaSlide are showing.

Comment: is there any specific functionality with this line if no, then just remove it. `((this.weightSlide = true) || (this.cardioSlide = true))`

Comment: please add your template part to know better about your requirement... and add console like  `console.log(data.userData);`

Comment: I think using `*ngIf=""` is better option and easy to use.